# How to Decrypt LDAP encrypted values(Like Password)

Tags: codeigniter, ldap

In codeigniter I wanted to decrypt all the encrypted field of LDAP , as we don't know that in which format It's encrypted so I'm facing the problem for the field which are decrypted as i needed those value as plain text.

Comment: LDAP doesn't encrypt passwords, it hashes them. This is the correct way to handle password security. You don't need to decrypt passwords, or rather if you do your application is radically insecure and should be redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the server ... one server might identify the encryption scheme in one way, another server might identify the encryption a different way. A professional-quality server can be configured with access controls that do not permit sensitive attributes from being retrieved by clients at all, and then how would one get the encrypted value to inspect for possible encryption schemes?

If the LDAP client desires to decrypt passwords, there is no need to do so anyway. When the server processes a BIND request, the server knows how to:

1. Decrypt the password if it's encrypted
2. Compare hashes if it's stored as a cryptographic hash digest.

In this case, LDAP clients never need to decrypt passwords at all.